# League of Legends with VirtualBox

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

Is it possible for me to run League of Legends (LoL) on Windows 7 in VBox? 
My specs:
intel i3
4 gb ram
512 mb VGA

Comment: lol??? what are you refering to?

Comment: With the 3D experimental support for Directx?.. yeah good luck trying to play. Can't even run Windows Aero..

Comment: On how to install lol, follow this: [League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu) All bug related issues should be asked on the lol Pol page [League Of Legends - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run Win7 on Virtualbox and it is amazing to see it encapsulated by Ubuntu!!!!! But as far as running LoL you may find it too slow and jerky, but it would be worth a try. But how about trying it with Wine instead? And this is a thread dedicated to running it on Linux: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=23686798

Comment: Ive been trying to install the game with wine for some time, but thanks for the answers